# Failed to load Native ad: 0 Error

Tags: android, admob, native-ads

I am implementing code for native ads that is given by google. That is working okay with `google`

**ad unit id ADMOB_AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110"**

But when I replace with my id its not showing ad and execute `onAdFailedToLoad` method and got   **Failed to load native ad: 0 error** .

```
I tried two different ad unit id but it didn't load ad.

so what should I do??please help me
```

I tried below code

```
final LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) appContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            AdLoader.Builder builder = new AdLoader.Builder(appContext, Global.ADMOB_AD_UNIT_ID);

            builder.forContentAd(new NativeContentAd.OnContentAdLoadedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onContentAdLoaded(NativeContentAd ad) {
                    //viewHolder.rlnativead.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    NativeContentAdView adView = (NativeContentAdView)li
                            .inflate(R.layout.ad_content, null);
                    populateContentAdView(ad, adView);
                    viewHolder.fl_adplaceholder.removeAllViews();
                    viewHolder.fl_adplaceholder.addView(adView);
                }
            });

            AdLoader adLoader = builder.withAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
//                  Toast.makeText(appContext, "Failed to load native ad: "
//                          + errorCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("Call List adapter","Failed to load native ad: "+errorCode);
                }
            }).build();

            adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

Comment: i got solution friends..this ADMOB_AD_UNIT_ID is for native expressview  so it will only use by native expressview .we can not use for advance native view currently native ad is in under beta

Answer (score 0):

Please add at least one testing device and try, It may be help you like following,

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder() .addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID") .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

this could be lately answered but expecting to help for others having similiar problem.One of the major cause for this is incorrect dimension

In my case before it was

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/native_ad_id"
    ads:adSize="320x250"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView>
```

I was making the mistake in giving the adSize ,so i just changed the add size with the below dimension and got fixed. Thanks.

```
 ads:adSize="320x250"
```